# Area of a triangle using double integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

What is the AREA of the triangle bounded by the lines $y=2x$  and $x=1$?

I solved it using single integration and i got $A=1$.  The problem is , I do not know how to solve it using double integration.

Comment: a triangle needs 3 sides. so you meant bounded by $y=2x$, $x=1$, $y=0$?

Comment: thay is the natural hypothesis, but it has to be confirmed by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Using double integration, the area is $$
\int_{0<x<1}\int_{0<y<2x} dxdy = \int_0^1 \left[\int_0^{2x} dy
\right]dx
=\int_0^1 \left[2x
\right]dx = \left[x^2
\right]_0^1 = 1
$$

Comment: So my solution goes like this :  inner  limit was 2x to 1 , outer is  from 0 to 2.  And inhot negativefor an answer.  But anyways i think i still have to work this out

Comment: Yeah i did draw the triangle.  Can you show me how you got those limits?

Comment: well, just to make sure we have the same drawing, this is ABC with A(0,0), B(1,0) and C(1,2).

Comment: now, the interior is the set of points for which $0<x<1$, and between the lines $y=0$ and $y=2x$ that is $0<y<2x$.

Comment: Yeah that is right and the line connecting A to C has the equation y=2x , right?  My problem is the limit, really

Comment: @kassandra: exacly.